# Play HTML audio on button click on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to make a simple keyboard in HTML. I understand playing HTML audio on iOS and android has some limitations, and I am having trouble working with them.

Here is what I have so far, the first column is based on listing 11 from [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/), the second is my previous attempt. They both work perfectly on desktop (Firefox and Chrome), but not on iOS (Chrome nor Safari). I don't have an android to test that. How do I make this work?

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body onload="loadScript();"style="background-color:#000000;">

  <script>
  function loadScript()
  {
    alert("ok");
    var button = document.getElementById('buttonD');
    var audio = document.getElementById('D');

    var onClickD = function() {
      audio.pause();
      audio.currentTime = 0;
      audio.play();
    };
    button.addEventListener('click', onClickD, false);
  }
  </script>

  <audio id="A" src="A.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
  <audio id="D" src="D.wav" preload="auto"></audio>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 clickable">
      <button id="buttonD" style="height:100%;width:100%;"type="button" class="btn btn-primary">D</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 clickable">
      <button type="button"  onclick="document.getElementById('A').pause;document.getElementById('A').currentTime = 0;document.getElementById('A').play();" style="height:100%;width:100%;"type="button" class="btn btn-success">A</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your HTML code into webview. So using webview for your HTML code can help you to play HTML audio.

Change A.wav with another audio file and try.

```
<audio id="A" src="phonecall.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="D" src="phonecall.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Comment: You are trying to play HTML audio into you ios app. right?

Comment: Then you can simply play the audio on your website. Why are you asking for ios and android?

Comment: Yes. If your code is working on the desktop then don't need to do any specific thing for a play that audio on ios and android device.

Comment: I have tried to run your code into safari browser and it is working fine.

Comment: @oxa11ce Yes. I mean try to use some other audio file.